# Adding "circle" to clickable javascript function

Tags: javascript, coordinates, shapes

I have js that allows a respondent to click on a specific shape/image and make it clickable.  Currently I have it set to allow rect and poly, but I want to add "circle" as a shape but I am not sure how to do this.  My code is here.  The "circle" code doesnt work.  I tried to reuse the poly script with no luck.  Kind of new to this so any help would be appreciated!

```
function addClickable(shape, coords) {
    area.push('<area class="area" href="#0" shape="' + shape + '" coords="' + coords.join(",") + '" style="outline: none;" title="" />');
    if (shape.toLowerCase() == "rect") {
        highlight.push('<rect x="' + coords[0] + '" y="' + coords[1] + '" width="' + (coords[2] - coords[0]) + '" height="' + (coords[3] - coords[1]) + '" style="fill-opacity:0.7; fill: none;" class="highlight" />');
    }
    if (shape.toLowerCase() == "poly") {
        var newCoords = coords.join(" ").replace(/(\d+)\s(\d+)\s/g, '$1, $2  ');
        highlight.push('<polygon  points="' + newCoords + '" style="opacity: 0.7; fill: none;" class="highlight" />');
    }
    if (shape.toLowerCase() == "circle") {
        var newCoords = coords.join(" ").replace(/(\d+)\s(\d+)\s/g, '$1, $2  ');
        highlight.push('<circle  points="' + newCoords + '" style="opacity: 0.7; fill: none;" class="highlight" />');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is highlight an array of SVG elements?

Comment: Yes, var area = [];
var highlight = [];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG's [`<circle>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) doesn't have a points attribute.

The syntax for `<circle>` is:

```
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
```

Also, cx and cy represent the **center** point of the circle.

Comment: Like this?    highlight.push('<circle  cx="' + coords[0] + '" cy="' + coords[1] + '"  r="' + coords[2] + '" style="opacity: 0.7; fill: none;" class="highlight" />');

Comment: As I'm seeing it in the documentation, yes, that should work just fine.